# Find the closest integer to $\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{5^6+1}-\sqrt[6]{5^6-1}}$

Tags: contest-math

This appeared in the Area Level of the 19th Philippine Mathematical Olympiad. Electronic calculators were not allowed during the competition of course. The closest I got to was to express it as:

$$
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[6]{2}(\sqrt[6]{7813}-\sqrt[3]{6}\sqrt[6]{217})}.
$$

The answer using an electronic calculator is 9375. Can anyone show how this can be approximated without the use of electronic calculators?

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. This is exactly a duplicate. I wish the original has more informative title though. I believe my question can be closed.

Comment: The title is not expressive, but you can use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search) for searching of math expressions on this site.

Comment: Will do from hereon @Sil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{x^6+1}-\sqrt[6]{x^6-1}}$$ and use series expansions for "large" values of $x$ for each piece and then long division.

You should end with
$$y=3 x^5-\frac{55}{72 x^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{19}}\right)$$

Comment: In this case, as we're interested in estimates at a _specific_ input value, I think the answer is not technically complete without estimates / upper bounds for the coefficient of any of the truncated terms. One cannot tell directly from what you've written here that the $x^{-19}$ term _doesn't_ have a coefficient of  size $5^{19}$ (or bigger). And what about the $x^{-31}$ term and so on? Of course, you're free to leave such details out, but I think it at least ought to be mentioned.